# What does this Mod Rewrite do?

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Can anybody tell me what this does?

```
RewriteRule .* .main.php [QSA,L]
```

From what I understand it will rewrite ANYTHING to main.php correct? But not so sure what the QSA,L does.

This is the whole .htaccess file, when I hit the main directory I get a 400 Bad Request error. **Edit:** Bad request went away when I added an ending slash in the browser to the root directory of this script.

```
RewriteEngine On


# Transfering to the main tranfer file

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.css$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.js$

RewriteRule .* .main.php [QSA,L]

# nobody is allowed to access the access the  INI file

<FilesMatch "\.inc.php$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QSA = Query String Append: append the existing query string to the re-written rule

L = Last Rule: last rule of the set, don't process any following `RewriteRule`

Check out the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule) for more.

Do you have a file that is named `.main.php`? The dot prefix worries me. Your rules read that unless the request is an exists, symbolic link, or it has a CSS or JS extension it goes to `.main.php`

Comment: Thanks. Yeah.... there is a file called .main.php, actually there is a lot of files in this script with a dot before their name... pretty weird actually. Though those dots are confusing me a bit too, don't they mean "any single character" in regex form?

Comment: FTR.. Bad request went away when I added an ending slash in the browser to the root directory of this script.

Comment: It should work with or without the slash. Comment with the URL, is this subdirectory? You are right as far as a dot matching any character. But the dot in this case is on the right side which is a literal string. The dot is probably prefixed as an additional security measure.

Comment: Ok thanks. URL isL http://www.condorstudios.com/work/jbeweb/hollywood-xposed/beta/